# UPDATE MySQL Query taking a long time to execute - ways to optimize

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a doubt with the following query.

```
update src_woz_waardeklasse_2011 a use index(waardeklasse_main,woz_val) 
inner join waardeklasse_average b use index (waardeklasse) 
on b.waardeklasse_new = a.waardeklasse 
set a.woz_value = b.average 
where b.waardeklasse_new = a.waardeklasse;
```

I am trying to update a new column 'woz_val' in the 'src_woz_waardeklasse_2011' table using the 'average' values from the 'waardeklasse_average' table. I am joining using the 'waaderklasse' numbers in both the tables. But the 'src_woz_waardeklasse_2011' table is nearly 7 million records and the 'waardeklasee_average' table is 46 records. So the query is taking a really long time. 25 minutes and counting.

Is there a way to optimize it? I am sure it's taking a long time as I am trying to compare values between a large table and a small table. I have included the table structure of both the tables below.

```
src_woz_waardeklasse_2011
+----------------------+---------------------------+------+-----+---------+-
---------------+
| Field                | Type                      | Null | Key | Default | 
Extra          |
+----------------------+---------------------------+------+-----+---------+-
---------------+
| id                   | int(11) unsigned          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | 
auto_increment |
| postcode             | varchar(150)              | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                
|
| huisnummeraanduiding | varchar(150)              | YES  |     | NULL    |                
|
| huisletter           | varchar(150)              | YES  |     | NULL    |                
|
 soort_woonobject     | varchar(150)              | YES  |     | NULL    |                
|
| bouwjaar             | varchar(150)              | YES  |     | NULL    |                
|
| bouwjaarsklasse      | varchar(150)              | YES  |     | NULL    |                
|
| inhoud               | varchar(150)              | YES  |     | NULL    |                
|
| reg_oppervlak        | varchar(150)              | YES  |     | NULL    |                
|
| woz_value            | int(15) unsigned zerofill | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                
|
| reg_oppervlak_bn     | varchar(150)              | YES  |     | NULL    |                
|
| waardeklasse         | int(10)                   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                
|
| waardepeildatum      | varchar(150)              | YES  |     | NULL    |                
|
| zipandnumber         | varchar(150)              | YES  |     | NULL    |                
|
+----------------------+---------------------------+------+-----+---------+-
---------------+

waardeklasse_average
+-------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| waardeklasse_average_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| waardeklasse_new        | int(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| lower                   | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| higher                  | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| average                 | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update src_woz_waardeklasse_2011 a use index(waardeklasse_main,woz_val) 
inner join waardeklasse_average b use index (waardeklasse) 
on b.waardeklasse_new = a.waardeklasse 
set a.woz_value = b.average
```

Where condition is not needed. As you had already mention that condition in **`On`** clause.

Try above query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had tried using that too but its still taking the same amount of time.

Comment: @Keshava How much data are there in both the table?

Comment: In the src_woz_wanderklasse_2011 table, there are over 7 million rows and in the wanderklasse_average table there is only 46 rows.

Comment: You can create index on both this `waardeklasse_new` and  `waardeklasse` column.
And then try to execute same query.

Comment: As mentioned in the code above, I have already made the indexes for both those columns as well(waardeklasse_main and waardeklasse).

Comment: `waardeklasse_new ` this column does not have index.And it is advisable to create index on column which are used in `ON` clause of `JOIN`

Comment: I have made the indexes but it is still taking longer than 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need the `where` clause.  Second, remove the index hints:

```
update src_woz_waardeklasse_2011 ww inner join
       waardeklasse_average wa 
       on wa.waardeklasse_new = ww.waardeklasse 
    set ww.woz_value = wb.average ;
```

Then, try an index on `src_woz_waardeklasse_2011(waardeklasse)`.  This should improve the execution plan.

You might also check that the 46 records in the second table actually correspond to 46 updates. If the join conditions are wrong, you could be updating all the records.

EDIT:

Indexes have nothing to do with your problem.  Updating 7 million records takes a long time.  You might consider creating the data you want in a temporary table and then truncating the original table and inserting the new rows into it.  Otherwise, batch the updates a few rows at a time.

Comment: There are numbers present between 0-46 in the 'waardeklasse' column of 'src_woz_waardeklasse_2011'. Each number corresponds to a value given in the 'waardeklasse_average' table. So it has to update all the 7 million records using those values.

Answer (score 0):

```
update src_woz_waardeklasse_2011 a use index(waardeklasse_main,woz_val) 
Left join waardeklasse_average b 
on b.waardeklasse_new = a.waardeklasse 
set a.woz_value = b.average 
where b.waardeklasse_new = a.waardeklasse;
```

Use the above query - in this you can use the left join and where condition to speed up the query.

Also don't use the index for the second table which has 46 record this will affect the performance - if the table has less records then index will create more burden in this case full table scan without index is lot better. Also if you have a cluster index in the first table(7 million) remove them and run the query, because for each and every update you perform default table structure And page alignment will be updated in the clustered index. Hope this helps..!